# Music player on Linux without playlists, just a directory navigation and file playing

Tags: linux, music, media-player

I am searching for a mp3 player for Linux that resembles 1by1 on features: light, free, with no playlists, just selection of files to play using a directory navigator. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [moc](http://moc.daper.net/), it does have a playlist window, but you can hide it and just play from the directory listing. It's what I turned to after giving up on new Amarok.

Comment: Wow.  You switched from Amarok to moc??  That is extremely hardcore.  +1 just for having more guts than me.

Comment: Well, I had to, have you seen the new Amarok? Besides, moc is pretty user friendly, it's just a bit picky who it's friends are :).

Answer (score 5):

I use [quodlibet](http://code.google.com/p/quodlibet/). A nice little player with comprehensive file-type support and fabulous metadata editing abilities. It has a "File System" view, which meets your criterion.

Comment: I just started using this myself.  It's great!  I'm suprised more people don't use it.  It seems to be flying 'under the radar' compared to other players.

Comment: i don't use QL, but i've used Ex Falso and Mutagen (the ID3 tagger & tagging library from the same project) for years.  really the only reason i haven't used QL is that my speakers are usually connected to a Windows system.

Comment: They've actually been working on a Windows port. Looks like it's available for download already, but I haven't tried it: http://code.google.com/p/quodlibet/wiki/Requirements

Answer (score 3):

`mpg123` and `mpg321` are commandline MP3 players.  You could associate them with MP3 files in Thunar/Nautilus/file-manager-of-choice.  They take a list of files/URLs to play as arguments:

```
$ mpg123 /path/to/mp3s/*.mp3
# plays all mp3 files in directory /pat/to/mp3s (generally in order of filename)

$ find /path/to/mp3s -name '*.mp3' -print0 | xargs -0 mpg123
# plays all mp3 files in /path/to/mp3s and subdirectories
```

See `man mpg123` or `man mpg321` for details.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen 1by1, but personally I use cplay when I want to both navigate and listen using the player.

For odd tracks, I have vlc associated with sound files, so I can navigate in Thunar (or whatever) and just double click on the file.

Answer (score 0):

i use mplayer for that - mplayer /path/to/folder/*.extention (or *.* or the name of a particular file) will play everything in there, or you can use a playlist. its incredibly simple, and works from command line ;p.