# Need audio player that lists by directory structure

Tags: linux, audio

Amarok is nice, and currently the only thing I've tried that will actually play audio from network shares and not lock up.  Only problem is that it doesn't seem to list my library by directory/folder structure.. only album/artist/genre or some variation thereof.  Is there anything that does list by folder structure?

Comment: You might find your answer here: http://superuser.com/questions/67618/music-player-on-linux-without-playlists-just-a-directory-navigation-and-file-pla

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[vlc](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) can visualize the directory structure in the playlist window if the corresponding setting `"Display playlist tree"` is enabled.

To do that, go to `"Tools->Preferences"` and enable the advanced settings. Then go to the playlist settings and check the `"Display playlist tree"` entry as shown below.

[image: vlc-preferences]

Restart vlc and you should see something like:

[image: vlc-playlist]

Moreover, vlc plays really well with network shares. In particular I use it daily for on-demand streaming via `sshfs`. See [my answer](https://superuser.com/questions/71782/vlc-stream-with-trickplay/71852#71852) to another question for more info.

Comment: nice. but is the media library location customizable?

Comment: The media library location can be configured following this instructions: http://superuser.com/a/421086/16752 .

Answer (score 1):

On windows, Foobar2000's album list can list by directory structure (Indeed, it's my preferred view), and I've had luck running it through Wine.

Not great if you're looking for something native, but worth keeping in mind if you can't get anything better.

Comment: I am indeed looking for something native.  :(  But thanks.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you have [1by1](http://mpesch3.de1.cc/1by1.html), an amazing little player with simple UI, very small footprint, lots of optional plugins and a great equalizer. If you open a file from a file manager into 1by1, it automatically displays it's parent directory open in the tree view list. It's simple and fast.

But on Linux, in the sea of audio players which imitate Amarok/XMMS there simply isn't one with this functionality. [Exaile](http://www.exaile.org/) for example, has a dir structure view, but you have to manually search through it and once you have a song playing, you cannot focus it's parent dir with one button. You have to search all the way back if you suddenly want to play next song in the album. It's absolutely absurt to have a dir structure view like that because I can drag and drop a file from Nautilus to almost any player made in GTK.