# VLC 2.0 - How to configure the Media Library?

Tags: windows, vlc-media-player

VLC's interface seems to imply that you can manage a collection of music without having to first open a playlist or folder. I assume my `"Media Library"` is empty, because the default root directory contains no media. How does the Media Library work?

I have set **Preferences > All > Playlists >** `[x] Use media library`, but I am not seeing any obvious method for configuring what goes into the Media Library. For example, `Media Library > Open Media` loads files into the playlist interface above it.

---

[image: use media library]

[image: open media]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

VLC's **Media Library** is actually a special [XSPF](http://wiki.videolan.org/XSPF) playlist, so managing folders and files in the Media Library view is comparable to that in the **Playlist** view.

After setting **Preferences > All > Playlists >** `[x] Use media library` as shown in the question body above, **Right-click** the area below the list columns (e.g. Title, Duration, Artist), and select an option from the context menu.

[image: right-click]

As an example, I have added my `Music` folder to the library.

[image: added a folder]

Comment: Seems like this doesn't work on Mac :(

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat On Mac, simply drag a folder from Finder and drop it in the empty area. (This also works on Windows from Explorer.)

Comment: Tried this and it seems as if this only gives me a view on the folder -- nothing the file manager won't do. Is there a way to have the contents of the lirbary grouped by albums, artists... or to search for those things, rather than having to go by filename?

Comment: @Zak If you mean in VLC, you can click the column headings to choose how to sort the media (Title, Time, Album, &c). When you import a folder, it will already be presorted by folder name (thus based on how you store your rips); I use Exact Audio Copy and chose to have a artist folder, followed by album folder, followed by file name, which provides a structure for VLC. Just above the playlist, there is a small square button with lines; clicking it will change how your playlist is displayed.

Answer (score -1):

Simply tap or click on title, Duration, or Artist to sort by them. you can drag them to rearrange their order also. Widen or full screen the VLC player to see everything.

Comment: The question asks about how to determine what goes into the library, not how to sort the items that are already in it.